# How to inflate correctly to respect view hierarchy?

Tags: java, android, navigation-drawer, android-inflate

I'm trying to have an DrawerLayout that is inflated by another layout whose function is to represent a mini media player at the bottom of the screen.7

Main Layout is Drawer Layout.
The layout I want to add (the one I inflate the main layout) is Relative layout.

Once I inflate the DrawerLayout (main layout) when I open the drawer and try to select some of the methods mentioned inside, they do not get triggered.

If I don't inflate the drawer and I hit some of the menu items in drawer, the methods trigger correctly.

I'm guessing it's something in the way I inflate, I tried to use VIEW.GONE on inflated view once the drawer is opened but the methods are still dummy.

How I call methods:

```
 switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {

                        case R.id.nav_home: {
                            if (checkInternetConnection(getApplicationContext())) {
                                Log.i(LOG_TAG, "PROVJERA NETA  POVEZAN");
                                start_loader();
                            } else {
                                mEmptyStateTextView.setText("Cannot connect to network, please check your network status and try again.");
                                // Clear the adapter of previous earthquake data

                            }

                            break;
                        }
                        case R.id.nav_history: {
                            //pozoviHistory(null);
                            break;
                        }
                        case R.id.nav_favourite: {
                            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "ZOVI HFAV");
                            pozoviFavorites();
                            break;
                        }

                    }
```

And this is how I inflate layouts:

```
DrawerLayout myLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.cili_test);
                View itemInfo1 = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.player2, myLayout, true);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from your post which layout your `DrawerLayout` is in. You say if you don't inflate the drawer you can still hit it's menu items which is not possible - the view needs to be inflated in order for it to be displayed.

I'm assuming `DrawerLayout` is in your activity/fragment layout since you're using `findViewById` to get a reference to it meaning it is already inflated once you call `setContentView` (or the equivalent in a `Fragment`).

---

What does `player2` layout look like? When it's inflated and added to `DrawerLayout` it's displayed on top of other views. Is it taking space over your drawer items so click events are not propagated to the items?

More code in your post would help finding the issue.